# Capybara returns gibberish

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I'm trying to use Capybara to select a row within a table containing a particular name. Unfortunately, Capybara only seems to see gibberish in the table. Here's what I get for the following code:

```
page.all('table tr').map { |e| e.text }
=> ["", "y y y w y", "y y w y", "y y y w y", "y y w y", "y y w y w y"]
```

*Update:* Here's the table it's trying to process:

```
<table class="views-table cols-5">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="views-field views-field-phpcode">Status</th>
      <th class="views-field views-field-name">Name</th>
      <th class="views-field views-field-field-id">ID</th>
      <th class="views-field views-field-phpcode-1">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd views-row-first">
      <td class="views-field views-field-phpcode">
        <img title="Complete" src="..."><br>Complete
      </td>
      <td class="views-field views-field-name">Harvey</td>
      <td class="views-field views-field-field-id">1</td>
      <td class="views-field views-field-phpcode-1">
        <a class="existing_submit disabled" href="...">Edit</a>
        <a class="existing_submit confirm-submit disabled" rel="Are you sure you want to reset?" href="...">Reset</a>
        <div style="clear: left;"></div>
        <a class="existing_submit disabled" href="...">Import</a>
        <a class="existing_submit disabled" target="_blank" href="...">View</a>
        <a class="existing_submit" target="_blank" href="...">Replay</a>
        <a class="existing_submit confirm-submit disabled" rel="Are you sure you want to submit the results?" href="...">Submit</a>
        <a class="existing_submit" target="_blank" href="...">Print</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="views-field views-field-phpcode">
        <img title="Complete" src="..."><br>Complete
      </td>
      <td class="views-field views-field-name">Lucas</td>
      <td class="views-field views-field-field-id">2</td>
      <td class="views-field views-field-phpcode-1">
        <a class="existing_submit disabled" href="...">Edit School</a>
        <a class="existing_submit confirm-submit disabled" rel="Are you sure you want to reset?" href="...">Reset</a>
        <div style="clear: left;"></div>
        <a class="existing_submit disabled" href="...">Import</a>
        <a class="existing_submit disabled" target="_blank" href="...">View</a>
        <a class="existing_submit" target="_blank" href="...">Replay</a>
        <a class="existing_submit confirm-submit disabled" rel="Are you sure you want to submit the results?" href="...">Submit</a>
        <a class="existing_submit" target="_blank" href="...">Print</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="views-field views-field-phpcode">
        <img title="Complete" src="..."><br>Complete               
      </td>
      <td class="views-field views-field-name">Sarah</td>
      <td class="views-field views-field-field-id">3</td>
      <td class="views-field views-field-phpcode-1">
        <a class="existing_submit disabled" href="...">Edit</a>
        <a class="existing_submit confirm-submit disabled" rel="Are you sure you want to reset?" href="...">Reset</a>
        <div style="clear: left;"></div>
        <a class="existing_submit disabled" href="...">Import</a>
        <a class="existing_submit disabled" target="_blank" href="...">View</a>
        <a class="existing_submit" target="_blank" href="...">Replay</a>
        <a class="existing_submit confirm-submit disabled" rel="Are you sure you want to submit the results?" href="...">Submit</a>
        <a class="existing_submit" target="_blank" href="...">Print</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="views-field views-field-phpcode">
        <img title="Complete" src="..."><br>Complete           
      </td>
      <td class="views-field views-field-name">Wanda</td>
      <td class="views-field views-field-field-id">4</td>
      <td class="views-field views-field-phpcode-1">
        <a class="existing_submit disabled" href="...">Edit</a>
        <a class="existing_submit confirm-submit disabled" rel="Are you sure you want to reset?" href="...">Reset</a>
        <div style="clear: left;"></div>
        <a class="existing_submit disabled" href="...">Import</a>
        <a class="existing_submit disabled" target="_blank" href="...">View</a>
        <a class="existing_submit" target="_blank" href="...">Replay</a>
        <a class="existing_submit confirm-submit disabled" rel="Are you sure you want to submit the results?" href="...">Submit</a>
        <a class="existing_submit" target="_blank" href="...">Print</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd views-row-last">
      <td class="views-field views-field-phpcode">
        <img title="Ready" src="..."><br>Ready          
      </td>
      <td class="views-field views-field-name">Herman</td>
      <td class="views-field views-field-field-id">5</td>
      <td class="views-field views-field-phpcode-1">
        <a class="existing_submit disabled" href="...">Edit</a>
        <a class="existing_submit confirm-submit" rel="Are you sure you want to reset?" href="...">Reset</a>
        <div style="clear: left;"></div>
        <a class="existing_submit" href="...">Import</a>
        <a class="existing_submit" target="_blank" href="...">View</a>
        <a class="existing_submit" target="_blank" href="...">Run</a>
        <a class="existing_submit confirm-submit disabled" rel="Are you sure you want to submit the results?" href="...">Submit</a>
        <a class="existing_submit disabled" target="_blank" href="...">Print</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Capybara is using Selenium, so I can see the page it's loaded, and the table doesn't resemble anything like what Capybara seems to be seeing.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Any ideas why it's is happening?

Comment: Including the `<table>`'s HTML might make it easier for someone to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Or a URL to the page with the table.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a disconnect between Capybara and Nokogiri. Using the `native` attribute provides the correct values:

`page.all('table tr').map { |e| e.native.text }`

Unfortunately, filters are also affected, so the following does not work:

`page.should have_selector("table", :text => "Harvey")`